# Как вписать несколько изображений в блок?

Tags: php, javascript

Интересует, как можно сделать эффект, аналогичный расположению изображений на стене vk.com, когда изображения выстраиваются в блок вне зависимости от количества и пропорций. При этом блок ограничен по горизонтали, количество элементов ограничено десятком.  Примеры привожу в виде скриншотов.

[image]
[image]
[image]

На ум пришло только masonry, но он не изменяет размеры элементов, чтобы они "вписались" в какой-либо блок, а просто располагает их друг за другом. Картиночки вк формируются на сервере (вернее, высчитываются у них размеры) и уже потом выстраиваются простыми float: left.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется здесь не обойтись без JS библиотеки. Первое, что нашел в гугле
http://jsfiddle.net/edlea/uZv3n/

https://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/

```
<div class="Collage effect-parent">
```

[image]

Причем библиотека отличная. Достаточно задать высоту строки и все работает. Есть даже эффекты отображения элементов. Бери не хочу)))